# Force reload another model's methods in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, model, associations

I have a model that defines methods based off of the entries in another model's table: eg Article and Type. An article habtm types and vice versa.

I define in Article.rb:

```
 Type.all.each do |type|
   define_method "#{type.name}?" do
     is?(:"#{type.name}")
   end
 end
```

This works great! it allows me to ensure that any types in the type db result in the methods associated being created, such as:

```
 article.type?
```

However, these methods only run when you load the Article model. This introduces certain caveats: for example, in Rails Console, if I create a new Type, its method article.type_name? won't be defined until I `reload!` everything.

Additionally, the same problem exists in test/rspec: if I create a certain number of types, their associated methods won't exist yet. And in rspec, I don't know how to reload the User model.

Does anyone know a solution here? Perhaps, is there some way to, on creation of a new Type, to reload the Article model's methods? This sounds unlikely.. Any advice or guidance would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll be better off avoiding reloading the model and changing your api a bit. In `Article`, are you really opposed to a single point of access through a more generic method?

```
def type?(type)
  return is? type if type.is_a? String # for when type is the Type name already
  is? type.name                        # for when an instance of Type is passed
end
```

If you're set on having separate methods for each type, perhaps something like this would work in your `Type` class

```
after_insert do
  block = eval <<-END.gsub(/^ {6}/, '')
    Proc.new { is? :#{self.name} }
  END

  Article.send(:define_method, "#{self.name}?", block)
end
```

Comment: yeah, I can see why this is better. however, i am developing on a pre-existing system, and some of it depends on article.type_name? i might just drop this if it's not possible..

Comment: Few more min and I'll update my answer; I'm working on an `after_insert` block you can add to `Type` to call `define_method` on `Article`

Comment: cool. just a thought: after_insert? or after_commit, which one would be more reliable?

Comment: Yeah, you can modify it to suit your needs. I hope this bumps you in the right direction. I'm still not convinced the `define_method` is a great idea, though that's coming from someone completely uninvested/uninformed in your application :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am trying it out. I don't  understand what the block = eval... end is doing, specifically the first line with END.gsub...?

Comment: hey @Deefour, your suggestion succeeds in defining a method, but the method definition doesn't work (always returns false even when it should return true)

Comment: @jay on the line you modified there should actually be no quotes; they're not necessary. As for the rest: The `eval` dynamically generates a new `Proc` to assign to the `block` variable. This is the only way I know to convert `:#{self.name}` to `:news` given some `'news'` `Type` instance. The `<<-END` & `END` defines a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). The weird `gsub` is a [trick](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/4438542511/heredoc-and-indent) for allowing indentation to be consistent visually *(the heredoc would typically be forced to have no leading whitespace)*

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: yeah - in the end it was decided this was not stable/reliable enough, like you mentioned, so we'll just use is?(role), but I greatly enjoyed learning how to do it!